# iOS Two different apps talk to each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an app that I want to release for iPhone and iPad. There is a feature in the app that allows data transfers via gamekit between other people who have the app.  I don't want to make the app universal.  I want an iPhone version and an iPad HD version. The iPhone version will be free and the iPad version will be paid.  My question is, will my iPhone app be able to "speak" to my iPad app if they are two separate apps?  The code base is the same for both iPhone and iPad as far as data transmission goes.

Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by speak? Exchanging data over the network? over iCloud? when installed on the same device?

Comment: I mean data transmission via GameKit. One user has an iPhone with the iPhone version of the app, another person has the iPad version of the app- I need both apps to be able to detect each other and transmit data. The code is in place for it, I just need to know if Apple allows it, or if my Bonjour services won't even be able to detect the other version of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two app's can speak using either GameKit over bluetooth or via Bonjour wifi. When you setup a GameKit session, you define the the session with a string identifier. This identifier is the key, as any app that includes the same identifier in it's code will be able to speak to other apps that use the same identifier regardless of what device or app bundle the user is running with.